# Discord.py Set role colour

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can I make that I create a new role and set a colour?

```py
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="member")
```

I want to set the role in green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a role with color with this line:

```
await guild.create_role(name="member", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use name="example", color=discord.Color.red()